# Sort data in google spreadsheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, pivot, transpose, google-sheets-query

I have a google form linked to a google sheet. The google form let me choose a date and select names. These persons are clients of a meeting at this date.
The google form gives me a date in the 1st column and a list of names separated by commas in the 2nd column. Eg

```
8.15.2020 John, Mike, Eva
8.20.2020 John, Eva, Gudrun, Pete
```

Now I want to sort this tab by names - 1st column list of names, 1st row list of meeting dates, an 'x' where the person joined the meetiing and save it in a new tab. Eg

```
           8.15.2020  8.20.2020
John          x           x 
Mike          x 
Eva           x           x
Gudrun                    x
Pete                      x
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(Sheet1!B1:B; ", "))="";;
 Sheet1!A1:A&"♦"&SPLIT(Sheet1!B1:B; ", "))); "♦"); 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1"))
```

[image: 0]

---

to get `x`es try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(Sheet1!B1:B; ", "))="";;
 Sheet1!A1:A&"♦"&SPLIT(Sheet1!B1:B; ", "))); "♦"); 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1")); "^\d+$"; "x"))
```

[image]

Comment: I've checked the solution and could understand the wy You solved the problem.

Comment: It perfectly solves my problem. Add 'unpivot' as an additional tag.